# Android Gradle Error - Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am having an issue when trying to run my project in Android Studio. It gives me one error with the gradle file. Gradle would not be my strongest point therefore, I could do with some help.

The error shown is:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ryans_000.iplan"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

The gradle console shows the following:

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
```

If anyone could help me out with this, I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks alot.

Comment: use gradlew assemble --info to get more details

Answer (score 0):

Under default config, add the following:

multiDexEnabled true

You may also want to add the following to your android object since it may be hitting a memory limitation when building:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Finally, try cleaning your project and running again.